# How to access the Event args while testing using ethers v6?

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, testing

I am trying to access an events argument(s) while running tests for my smart contract using node.js/chai. Recently moved to using ethers v6, and the code that works on v5 is no longer valid.
Namely:

```js
vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")

const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()

const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)

subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
```

Used javascript debug Terminal and I see the contract and the transactionResponse and Receipt but I don't see the events objects in transactionReceipt as I did with ethers v5.

Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong or what the correct method is for ethers v6 but I am struggling.

I have tried to read the [ethers v6 documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/) but struggling to get an answer from it (newbie and reading documentation is something I am still working on). Any help is most welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the `transactionReceipt`, the logs property contains an array of log objects emitted during the transaction. Each log object has a topics property that holds an array of topic values. The topic value you need should be at index 1 of the topics array.

Try to the change code like this:

```js
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer);
            const transaction = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
            const transactionReceipt = await transaction.wait(1)
            subscriptionId = BigInt(transactionReceipt.logs[0].topics[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue while writing code since I was using TypeScript. I think the problem is not with `ethers.js` cause they provide an `events` property that only available on a `ContractReceipt` you can check [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2207).

But the `transactionReceipt` here is of type `ContractTransactionReceipt` as returned by `createSubscription()` function.

So `events` property do not exist on type `ContractTransactionReceipt`, I think ChainLink must update their documentation, to get the subscription id.